# will Apache CXF supports JAX-RPC based web services(SOAP)

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rpc

I want to know if Apache CXF supports JAX-RPC based web services. Currently I have worked on JAX-WAS based one.

Thanks.

Comment: The direct answer is "no" - CXF implements JAX-WS, not JAX-RPC.  But a better question would be to give an example of the kind of SOAP message you need to generate/consume and we can help you find out whether there's a way to achieve that using CXF.  Generally anything document/literal should be possible in CXF, but not old-style rpc/encoded.

Comment: @IanRoberts. I have created a web service in Apache CXF using JAX-WS. I wanted to convert this to JAX-RPC. Thank you

Comment: Read [Paulius's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14831989/592139) - your question makes no sense.  JAX-WS and JAX-RPC aren't "types of web service", they're different specifications for web service toolkits.  Can you give an example of the kind of WSDL you need to handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache CXF in terms of `SOAP` web services supports `document/literal` WSDL style. There is no such thing as `Apache CXF supports JAX-RPC`. JAX-RPC is a different stack for creating web services and CXF is based on `JAX-WS`. So probably you wanted to know if Apache CXF supports `rpc/encoded` style web services. The answer is no. It does not support them.

**See also:**

- [Which style of WSDL should I use](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/ws-whichwsdl/)