# Document style in Apache CXF webservices

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf

I have a requirement to implement different type of document style in Apache CXF webservices according to there role.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: please give an example of "document style" (ie `@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)`?)

Comment: see the answer on this question, it might help

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831499/will-apache-cxf-supports-jax-rpc-based-web-servicessoap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831499/will-apache-cxf-supports-jax-rpc-based-web-servicessoap)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/

You can follow above link to understand differences between them with example.